# How to change Xaml page title dynamically in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I change my Xaml page title dynamically in a WPF application?

Answer (score 12):

You can set page's Title by set [Title property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.title.aspx) in your code.

```
this.Title = "My Application" + DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Make sure this comes after the call to `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
this.WindowTitle = "Your title here";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function like this

```
public void SetPageTitle(dynamic title)
{
  string DefaultTitle = "Name";
  try
  {
    this.Title = title.ToString();
  }
  catch
  {
    this.Title = DefaultTitle;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you possibly want a dynamic parameter here?

Comment: So that the function could be used with different inputs like what Ekk did in this this.Title = "My Application" + DateTime.Now;

Comment: simply having a parameter of type object would allow you to call ToString() on it. The above would not change in any way except to have (object title) instead of (dynamic title)

Comment: but it would require a cast or boxing before you could use it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "THIS", you can use the name of your window.

```
MainWindow.Title = "My Window";
```