# fetching the name of a file and displaying it on the title window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a media player like VLC in C#. I want to display the name of the file on the title window which is currently loaded. I don't know how to do it. I have searched a lot about it but i was not able to get the right answer from the links [Set a taskbar text different from the Window title in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627772/set-a-taskbar-text-different-from-the-window-title-in-wpf) and [can I add text box beside the title of WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700270/can-i-add-text-box-beside-the-title-of-wpf-window).

I have also problem in fetching the name of the file. when fetching the name of the file, i am getting the whole path not only the name of the file. I am not getting the idea from the link [How to get only filenames within a directory using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140081/how-to-get-only-filenames-within-a-directory-using-c)

```
 mediaElement.Source = new Uri(loadfile.FileName);
 this.Title =loadfile.FileName;
```

now the file name id not the file name but the complete path. How to get only the name of the file.
 Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060161/how-to-change-xaml-page-title-dynamically-in-wpf ?

Comment: @tmack but what about the path it is fetching. i want to fetch only the name of the file not the whole path.

Comment: var fi = new FileInfo("path/to/file.ext");
            string filename = fi.Name;

Answer (score 0):

You can bind window title to a property in code behind.
for instance :

```
<Window title={Binding ToMyProperty} /> etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the file name from a file path, you can use the Path.GetFileName method which is in System.IO namespace. This will return the file name from the provided path.

I have modified the example you provided, to do what you described:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(loadfile.FileName);
this.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(loadfile.FileName);
```

Hope that helps.